# How do I place a placeholder inside a select type input?

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I'm having a rather weird issue and I just can't seem to figure it out. So I have a form where the user selects which country they're from and I'd like to code in a placeholder to make it look better. I've connected a REST api to fetch all the countries in the world and display them as options.

I've tried the `html <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country...</option>` and few other similar ones. I believe it has something to do with the way I coded the javascript to fetch the API but since I'm a novice I'm not too sure.

```
// set up global variables
const countriesList = document.getElementById("country");
let countries; //contains fetched data list

//establish connection with API
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => initialize(data))
.catch(err => console.log("Error: " + err));


function initialize(countriesData) {
countries = countriesData;
let options = ""; //assign option vriable empty string

// loop each country and assign it to options variable
for(let i=0; i<countries.length; i++){
  options += `<option value= "${countries[i].name}"> ${countries[i].name} </option>`;
}
countriesList.innerHTML = options;
}
```

Above is the javascript I used in order to fetch the api and display it in the drop down select menu, and the issue is that the api replaces every option tag I manually input in the html code. Any suggestions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have one `option` in the `select`, acting as the placeholder:

```
<select id=country>
    <option value=''>Select...</option>
</select>
```

Then have the JavaScript append the generated HTML, rather than replace the current HTML.

```
countriesList.innerHTML += options;
```

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if you deem it to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a smaller setup that may help, too:

```js
const createElements = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
  const countries = await response.json();

  return countries.map(({ name }) => `<option value=${name}>${name}</option>`);
};

(async () => {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <select>
      <option>select</option>
      ${await createElements()}
    </select>
  `;
})();
```

```html
<div id="app"/>
```